# Efficient way to access/store data instead of having a huge constructor class

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm currently in need of some guidance. Instead of making a huge constructor class with gets/sets. Is it possible to simplify this task?

Trying to avoid having a huge constructor with gets/sets. So I'm assuming what's a good way to avoid doing something like this. How can this sort of thing be simplified significantly?

```
public User(int id, String name, long skillPoints) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.skillPoints  = skillPoints;
        this.level = 0;
        // So on so forth
}
```

Comment: Redis has exactly zero to do with creating small constructors. This question is far too broad and it is not understandable what you want to achieve, why and how redis would have anything to do with that.

Comment: @luk2302 Let me make it a bit more clear. I'm trying to access/store user data. What I'm more familiar with is making a constructor class with the defined fields and cache the data inside a hashmap or Redis. Then retrieve it accordingly. The project I'm currently working on is a bit more complex and a lot more data is being stored so making a constructor class with the defined fields is just crazy.

Comment: I do not see why I have been down-voted (plus without any comment), Kotlin is official for Android and 100% integrated in intelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/setup/android)?
By adding the annotation @Data you will get a shortcut for @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter on all fields, @Setter on all non-final fields, and @RequiredArgsConstructor. And there are plenty more annotations you can check out!

#### With Lombok

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data public class DataExample {
  private final String name;
  @Setter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE) private int age;
  private double score;
  private String[] tags;

  @ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
  @Data(staticConstructor="of")
  public static class Exercise<T> {
    private final String name;
    private final T value;
  }
}
```

#### Vanilla Java

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DataExample {
  private final String name;
  private int age;
  private double score;
  private String[] tags;

  public DataExample(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
  }

  public void setScore(double score) {
    this.score = score;
  }

  public double getScore() {
    return this.score;
  }

  public String[] getTags() {
    return this.tags;
  }

  public void setTags(String[] tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
  }

  @Override public String toString() {
    return "DataExample(" + this.getName() + ", " + this.getAge() + ", " + this.getScore() + ", " + Arrays.deepToString(this.getTags()) + ")";
  }

  protected boolean canEqual(Object other) {
    return other instanceof DataExample;
  }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof DataExample)) return false;
    DataExample other = (DataExample) o;
    if (!other.canEqual((Object)this)) return false;
    if (this.getName() == null ? other.getName() != null : !this.getName().equals(other.getName())) return false;
    if (this.getAge() != other.getAge()) return false;
    if (Double.compare(this.getScore(), other.getScore()) != 0) return false;
    if (!Arrays.deepEquals(this.getTags(), other.getTags())) return false;
    return true;
  }

  @Override public int hashCode() {
    final int PRIME = 59;
    int result = 1;
    final long temp1 = Double.doubleToLongBits(this.getScore());
    result = (result*PRIME) + (this.getName() == null ? 43 : this.getName().hashCode());
    result = (result*PRIME) + this.getAge();
    result = (result*PRIME) + (int)(temp1 ^ (temp1 >>> 32));
    result = (result*PRIME) + Arrays.deepHashCode(this.getTags());
    return result;
  }

  public static class Exercise<T> {
    private final String name;
    private final T value;

    private Exercise(String name, T value) {
      this.name = name;
      this.value = value;
    }

    public static <T> Exercise<T> of(String name, T value) {
      return new Exercise<T>(name, value);
    }

    public String getName() {
      return this.name;
    }

    public T getValue() {
      return this.value;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
      return "Exercise(name=" + this.getName() + ", value=" + this.getValue() + ")";
    }

    protected boolean canEqual(Object other) {
      return other instanceof Exercise;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (o == this) return true;
      if (!(o instanceof Exercise)) return false;
      Exercise<?> other = (Exercise<?>) o;
      if (!other.canEqual((Object)this)) return false;
      if (this.getName() == null ? other.getValue() != null : !this.getName().equals(other.getName())) return false;
      if (this.getValue() == null ? other.getValue() != null : !this.getValue().equals(other.getValue())) return false;
      return true;
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
      final int PRIME = 59;
      int result = 1;
      result = (result*PRIME) + (this.getName() == null ? 43 : this.getName().hashCode());
      result = (result*PRIME) + (this.getValue() == null ? 43 : this.getValue().hashCode());
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add [Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/get-started.html) to your project, is becoming the standard, solves your problem as a charm,  and as is officially supported by Google, you do not have any problem if you go in production, instead to use other libraries( that could have bugs).
Do not think that you cannot manage to transform all the project from Java to Kotlin, because Kotlin is 100 per cent compatible. One of the K features of Kotlin is just to solve your problem: avoiding to have constructor linked to instance variables and getter and setter, is a lot of boiler plate code. 
you just add Kotlin to your project, will take less than 3 minutes, then you can change only the [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) classes, this is the name/acronym of the plain classes you are referring with constructors, getter and setters.

After you installed Kotlin, use [Data Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)
in this way a class with 86 lines like the following will become one line. Is worthy to do it, **even if you are not going to implement Kotlin to the rest of your project**

```
public class Movie {

private String name;
private String studio;
private float rating;

public Movie(String name, String studio, float rating) {
    this.name = name;
    this.studio = studio;
    this.rating = rating;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getStudio() {
    return studio;
}

public void setStudio(String studio) {
    this.studio = studio;
}

public float getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(float rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;

    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + Float.floatToIntBits(rating);
    result = prime * result + ((studio == null) ? 0 : studio.hashCode());

    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;

    if (obj == null)
        return false;

    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    Movie other = (Movie) obj;

    if (name == null) {            
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;

    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;

    if (Float.floatToIntBits(rating) != Float.floatToIntBits(other.rating))
        return false;

    if (studio == null) {
        if (other.studio != null)
            return false;

    } else if (!studio.equals(other.studio))
        return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Movie [name=" + name + ", studio=" + studio + ", rating=" + rating + "]";
}
}
```

will become just
[this](http://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-data-classes) and will get for free also `toHash` and `toString`:

```
data class Movie(var name: String, var studio: String, var rating: Float)
```